# How to add onesignal to expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal

I want to add onesignal push notification to expo project.

However, i need to add something like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

to

> app/build.grandle

but expo project doesnt include build.grandle folder

how can i handle this

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **you can't**.

Checkout [The only supported third-party push notification service is the Expo notification service](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/).

If you want to use OneSignal with expo, you have to eject to the bare workflow. Here's a link to OneSignal documentation: [Must eject to bare workflow](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#step-2-add-the-onesignal-package-to-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

Native Notify (https://nativenotify.com) is the only Expo push notification service I know of that works with Expo.

I think Native Notify was designed specifically to be an Expo posh notification service.

It was SOOOO easy to set up. I was set up in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. `expo install onesignal-expo-plugin`
2. `npm install --save react-native-onesignal`
3. In your app.json add

```html
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "onesignal-expo-plugin",
      {
        "mode": "development",
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

4. Run `npx expo prebuild`
5. In one terminal run this

   `npx expo start --dev-client`
6. Then in another terminal run this

   `npm run android`
7. Now add this in your code

```html
import { LogLevel, OneSignal } from "react-native-onesignal";

OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(LogLevel.Verbose);
OneSignal.initialize("Your-Api-Key");
```

8. And to get player Id

```html
    const player_id = OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.getPushSubscriptionId();
```